# Global String in Installshield

Tags: string, variables, installshield

I am trying to do have a global string in Installshield so I can access it in multiple places. This is my first run at scripting in it.  Here is what I have:

```
STRING DIR;

....

DIR="c:\\tempdir";

function Completed_Action()
begin
    // Here is where I try to access the DIR string.
```

It keeps giving me errors though.  Is there any way to have a global string and set it's value before any functions?  I should also add that this is in a sub rul script that is called after the main Setup.rul.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using InstallShield 11.5 and earlier, you can initialize any variables in an `OnBegin` method.

With InstallShield 12 and later, use `MsiSetProperty` and `MsiGetProperty(hMSI, "MyVariable", szSupportDir, nLen)` to set and fetch global variables because when a Basic MSI installation executes an InstallScript custom action, the compiled InstallScript is loaded before the action is called, and it is unloaded after the action completes.

Comment: If you have multiple scripts in the install process, can each one have an onBegin?  I tried putting them in the onBegin in the initial file to launch (I am using them in a Component one) but, I got the same errors basically.  It seems they have to be in the script I need them in?

Comment: Actually it worked now in OnBegin.  I must have had it in there wrong. THANKS!